# jQuery Each() as a For statement?

Tags: jquery, for-loop, each

I have a jQuery.each() function that I would like to turn into a FOR statement.

I was wondering how I can turn

```
     jQuery('.myclass').each(function() {
       //do stuff
     }
```

into a

```
   for ( var i=0; i<.myclass.length; i++) {
    //do stuff
   }
```

?

Comment: Why? The result is practically identical.

Comment: @Juhana: `each` involves repeated function calls and messes with the value of `this`. There are lots of times when a good old-fashioned loop is the better choice. There are also times when `each` is the better choice.

Comment: @Juhuna - further I think you also need to review this http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/6 - will change your view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery objects are array-like. They have a `length` property and they support accessing elements by using numeric indexes with `[]`. So you just index directly into the resulting object:

```
var myclass = jQuery('.myclass');

for ( var i=0; i<myclass.length; i++) {
    // use myclass[i] here
}
```

This information isn't especially flagged up in the API docs, but you can find it in the documentation of the [`get` function](http://api.jquery.com/get/). The bracket notation largely replaces use of the `get` function except for its handling of negative index values (which are used to index relative to the end of the collection; negative indexes are only supported via `get`, not via `[]`).

Comment: thanks a bunch :) reviewed this and was a bit :O - http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/6

Comment: @ssDille: Note that your `for..in` test case does something completely different than a standard for loop. Details: *[Myths and realities of `for..in`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)*

Comment: @TJ - thanks for the link. yeah - but generally my understanding is that the `for` loop about is faster than the `.each()` ?

Comment: @ssDille: *"...but generally...the `for` loop about is faster than the `.each()`?"* Dramatically, yes. Of course, probably 99.99%+ of the time you don't care, because you're only looping through a few elements and so while there's an absolute difference, there's no *perceptible* difference. I wouldn't get hung up on it until/unless you see an actual issue (be sure to test on IE; it's quite slow and thus good for discovering performance issues). `for` has the issue that you have to manage the index; `each` has the `this` issue and the potential for speed cost. Each (no pun) has its place. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.get()` to get a standard JavaScript array. And then use a for loop in the normal way.

```
var nodes = $(...).get(),
    nodes_len = nodes.length;

for(var i=0; i < nodes_len; i++) {
   var node = nodes[i];

   ...
}
```

---

Or, if you just need the index number, use the following:

```
$(...).each(function (index) {
   ... 
});
```

Comment: yea i was going to mention the index option as well +1.

Comment: There's no need to call `get()` first.